# Import stock transactions from Excel to GnuCash

Tags: stocks, gnucash

I'm trying to automatize the process of import financial data from my stock broker to Gnucash. I'm looking for a way of export the Excel data from my broker to QIF of other suitable format to be imported by GnuCash.
Here is an example:

```
Date         Action   Memo              Stock code   quantity    Unity value
13/10/2017   Buy      RNGO11 108 Buy    RNGO11       108         77,26
```

I transfer money from my other account to my broker account and after I buy or sell the stocks. So, in the transaction above, I have a certain amount of money transferred from my bank account to my broker account and I want to register the buying of 108 units of stock RNGO11 at 77,26 each unit. I have a destination account called RNGO11 to receive the stock quantities.

Is it possible to do it by CSV or by QIF (using XLF2QIF tool)?

Comment: Does File / Import / Import Transactions from CSV not handle stocks?

Comment: I tried it. I created a fake transaction, exported it to CSV and tried to import it again. GnuCash keep saying that the columns are not correct.

Answer (score 1):

GnuCash can import both the list of accounts, and the transactions, from .csv files. However, the .csv files need to have fields in the order that GnuCash expects.
The best way to do this is to look at .csv exports from GnuCash, of both the chart of accounts and the transactions. Then, in Excel or OpenOffice or whatever, write the formulas you need to massage the data (still in the spreadsheet) into the order that GnuCash wants. Then, and only then, export the data from Excel to .csv . After that you can import them into GnuCash.

Comment: This answer is a bit outdated after the CSV importer was rewritten. It is now possible to customize the .csv file structure but some fields are mandatory, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can, in GnuCash 4.9, tell the importer what columns are what, but it doesn't seem to handle a CSV that contains multiple stock symbols or dividends/transfers